# What's the opposite of "retaliate"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a single word to mean: "to do something positive to someone because they have done or said something positive to you", when you want to return the favour with something equal or better.

I Googled it and I found some odd results like "forgive" and "sympathize".

Comment: @Boob: Your use of the word *gratitude* there is incorrect. Don't worry about repeating the word *positive* - that's perfectly ok in a sentence like yours where a "two-way" meaning is intended anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks a lot, you can read my mind.

Comment: @Boob: haha I really did think you probably agonised a bit over that one! I hope you don't mind that I just rephrased the last part for you myself - it would have gotten a bit complicated to suggest better wording in a comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Oh no, now others don't notice that my English sucks.;) So kind of you, thanks.

Comment: @Boob: We do like to offer a full service here at EL&U - ask for one way to improve your English, and we'll throw in a couple more for free!  :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Eh, really? I'd like to try everything .. ahem .. for free! ;) anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Reciprocate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reciprocate) does it for me.

There is also [requite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/requite). But this is much less common, and slightly archaic, and mainly only seen as a negative past participle in *unrequited love*. I wouldn't recommend it for general use.

Answer (score 3):

- *"repay"* (note: I disagree with you comment on MT_Head's answer that this is dominated by negative connotations. It is used both ways)

While it's not one word, I am fond of:

- *"return the favor"*

Comment: I wouldn't say 'repay' is *dominated* by negativity, but I do think both it, and to an even greater extent 'pay back', lean more in that direction. +1 for *return the favour* though. Which I edited into OP's question where he'd originally written *you're looking for a situation to do something equally or more*.

Answer (score 2):

"Reward", "recompense", "honor" (if you happen to be royalty!), "pay back" (although this can be used in both a positive and negative connotation.)

Comment: "Pay back" and "repay" are used more in negative connotation, as I found out.

Comment: @Boob - Dearly beloved, avenge not yourselves, but [rather] give place unto wrath: for it is written, Vengeance [is] mine; I will repay, saith the Lord.  [link](http://bible.cc/romans/12-19.htm)

Comment: @MT_Head: "I will take revenge; I will pay them back," says the LORD. [same link] I meant words with positive meanings, only.

Comment: @Boob - I was agreeing with you that "repay" has negative connotations; that passage must be the most famous usage of the word, and nobody could call it a positive connotation!

Comment: @MT_Head:By the way, thanks for your suggestions, it helped.

Comment: @Boob - my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

What about "make up"?

> I am trying to make up for what he has done for me.

Comment: I think it's more common to 'make up' for something *you* did.