# What is antonym (?) for vengence/revenge?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [opposite of “retaliate”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26503/opposite-of-retaliate)

What is antonym (?) for vengence/revenge?

The "?" after antonym is because the given antonyms : "forgiveness, pardon" are not what I am after, Something more along the lines of somebody does you favour and you try to get them back by doing something good.

In this context what is a better word than antonym? for example what would be antonyms for "War"? and by that I don't mean peace, it needs to be something stronger, something that poeple actively do, like getting together and building something for some other community, and in retaliation (?) another group builds/helps them in some way without being expected to do so.

Consider that in Paris there are anti-vandal(?)  groups where they break into ignored/decaying historical places and restor them illegally/without permission ( the show was on PBS ).

Every word prior to "(?)" requires a better word choice in it's place

Comment: This questino is certainly a duplicate of the linked one, but, despite an answer being 'accepted' there, there really doesn't seem to be a single-word answer. 'reciprocate' is the neutral version (vengeance is the bad kind of reciprocation, but there's no 'good' version).

Comment: @FumbleFingers : yes it seems to be a duplicate, but maybe the answers end up being different, But Mitch also has a point.

Comment: @Arjang,Mitch: Agreed my *reciprocate* on the original is usually more "neutral" than might be wanted in some contexts, but it seems to me OP here is looking for a pretty odd spread of meaning anyway. Stretching from "positively reciprocal" in respect of "favour" given by some other community, to "socially restorative" in respect of "noble endeavours" done by a past generation who erected impressive but now-neglected buildings. In the end, I think this question as it stands is a bit too broad anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Benevolence" is the first thing that comes to mind, though it's not necessarily quid pro quo good-for-good.